# Replace last two occurences of commas with dots

Tags: sed

In each line in I want to replace last two commas with dots

I found such two sed piped method but it does not work with sed on MacOS

```
$ echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1./'|sed 's/\(.*\),/\1./'
abc,def.12379.foo
```

Would there be a way which will work with any sed version? Not necessarily with sed only.

Comment: How does it fail on MacOS?

Comment: Can you add `-e` to the sed command? So like this: `echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' | sed -e 's/\(.*\),/\1./'|sed -e 's/\(.*\),/\1./'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' | sed 's/,\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)$/.\1.\2/'
abc,def.12379.foo
```

This will leave lines with a single comma alone (eg `foo,bar`). That may or may not be what you want.

`\(...\)` capture groups and `\1`, `\2` backrerefences in the replacement string should be supported in all versions of `sed`; I've tested the above on Unix v7.

PS. Even the double sed from your question should work on MacOS; maybe your problem is that the lines are [terminated by CarriageReturns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489825/308316) instead of LineFeeds?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' | sed -e 's/\(.*\),/\1./' -e 's/\(.*\),/\1./'
```

or

```
echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' | sed -e 's/\(.*\),/\1./;s/\(.*\),/\1./'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, treating the input as a set of comma-delimited fields, and joining the three last fields with dots,

```
echo 'abc,def,12379,foo' |
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { print $1, $2 "." $3 "." $4 }'
```